# Sum query not getting right output in sqlite

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, sum

Hello friends i have 3 tables like below  :

```
property_master -->p_id, p_name,r_id

transction_master -->t_id,p_id,amount,user_cat_id,r_id

user_trans_cat-->user_cat_id,cat_name,trans_id ,r_id
```

my query as  below

```
SELECT property_master.p_id AS "Product Code",
   property_master.p_name AS "Description",
   (SELECT SUM(amount)
    FROM transction_master ,property_master

   JOIN user_trans_cat ON transction_master.user_cat_id = user_trans_cat.user_cat_id
   WHERE user_trans_cat.trans_id =1 and transction_master.date between   '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
   group by property_master.p_id
   ) AS "Income",
   (SELECT SUM(amount)
    FROM transction_master ,property_master

   JOIN user_trans_cat ON transction_master.user_cat_id = user_trans_cat.user_cat_id
    WHERE user_trans_cat.trans_id =2 and transction_master.date between   '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
   group by property_master.p_id
   ) AS "Expense"
   FROM property_master   ,transction_master where  property_master.r_id = 1

   Group by property_master.p_id
```

**Transaction table**
[image]

**Output Came** 
[image]
i want total income , expense value as per proeprty wise but when i run above query it will gave me total income value for all property any idea how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about below -

```
select
pm.p_id AS "Product Code",
pm.p_name AS "Description",
sum( case when utrc.trans_id =1 then tm.amount else 0 end ) as "Income",
sum( case when utrc.trans_id =2 then tm.amount else 0 end ) as "Expense"
from transction_master tm
join property_master pm on pm.p_id = tm.p_id
join user_trans_cat utrc on utrc.user_cat_id = tm.user_cat_id
where 
tm.date between   '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
group by 
pm.p_id
```

> **UPDATE** : If you need all the property to be listed even if they are
>   not in transaction master then you need to change the query to select
>   from property_master and then left join as

```
from property_master pm
left join transction_master tm on pm.p_id = tm.p_id
left join user_trans_cat utrc on utrc.user_cat_id = tm.user_cat_id
```

Now left join with where condition is nothing but inner join so the where condition needs to be moved as joining condition so the query becomes

```
select
pm.p_id AS "Product Code",
pm.p_name AS "Description",
sum( case when utrc.trans_id =1 then tm.amount else 0 end ) as "Income",
sum( case when utrc.trans_id =2 then tm.amount else 0 end ) as "Expense"
from property_master pm
left join transction_master tm on pm.p_id = tm.p_id
and tm.date between   '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
left join user_trans_cat utrc on utrc.user_cat_id = tm.user_cat_id 
group by 
pm.p_id
```

Comment: Abhik Chakraborty :total getting right but your query not listed that property which has no transaction value in transaction _master i nedd that property also in listing so any idea how can i make it happen?

Comment: You may change the query as `from property_master pm
left join transction_master tm on pm.p_id = tm.p_id
left join user_trans_cat utrc on utrc.user_cat_id = tm.user_cat_id`

Comment: i tried by changeing left join like below 
`select
pm.p_id AS "Product Code",
pm.p_name AS "Description",
sum( case when utrc.trans_id =1 then tm.amount else 0 end ) as "Income",
sum( case when utrc.trans_id =2 then tm.amount else 0 end ) as "Expense"
from transction_master tm
left join property_master pm on pm.p_id = tm.p_id
left join user_trans_cat utrc on utrc.user_cat_id = tm.user_cat_id
where 
tm.date between   '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
group by 
pm.p_id`
but still not getting all proeprty which has not transaction value

Comment: Yes the where condition is causing the issue it should be as joining condition, check my update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this mate:

```
SELECT
    pm.p_id 'Product Code',
    pm.p_name 'Description',
    SUM(CASE WHEN utc.r_id = 1 THEN tm.amount ELSE 0 END) 'Income',
    SUM(CASE WHEN utc.r_id = 2 THEN tm.amount ELSE 0 END) 'Expense'
FROM
    transction_master tm
    JOIN property_master pm ON tm.p_id = pm.p_id
    JOIN user_trans_cat utc ON utc.trans_id = tm.t_id
WHERE
    tm.date BETWEEN '2015-12-31' AND '2015-01-01'
GROUP BY
    pm.p_id;
```

Comment: Avidos : i tried your query but i gave me error message like **no such column: utc_income.amount**

Comment: stiill i gave you +1 for your  effort brother

Comment: Updated, you can try that if you want. Thanks